# Create stacked bar chart for column based on unique levels of another dataframe column with plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have the dataframe below and I would like to create a stacked bar chart with plotly for every `country`. The differents "stacks" will be the `Year` values

```
country<-c("AFG","AFG","ALB","ALB")
Year<-c("2019","2020","2019","2020")
value<-c(4,5,6,7)
note<-data.frame(country,Year,value)

fig <- plot_ly(mote, x = ~country, y = ~value, type = 'bar')
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~)
fig <- fig %>% layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'stack')

fig
```

Comment: There are few typos in your post. You are creating `note` but using `mote`. `fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~)` is incomplete.

Comment: yes cause I do not know what to type there